# Heat maps of Bible citation patterns using ggplot2

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, heat

I am looking for a way to represent differential Biblical citation patterns between churches.  The most obvious way I've thought of is to create heat maps.  My idea is basically to represent the Bible by a long, horizontal rectangle, with different books as blocks within that rectangle, each colored according to its frequency of citation by a particular church.

The data I have are simply two rows.  The first consists of the book titles as headings (e.g. 01 Genesis, 02 Exodus, 03 Leviticus, ... , 66 Revelation).  The second consists of the numbers of times each book has been cited by a particular church (5, 0, 2, etc.).

Most tutorials I've seen on creating heat maps with ggplot2 assume that the user wants a two dimensional representation of the data.  I really don't, at least not at this point.  It's not clear, though, how to proceed if you only have one dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You have two-dimensional data (book and count), but you have multiple data sets (churches).

It sounds like you would need one heat map per church, or one heat map for ALL churches (making it impossible to distinguish between churches on the heat map).

I think a bar graph would make more sense in this case.

```
4| $
3| $          %         $ - church A
2| $%        $%         % - church B
1| $%        $%
0|_$%________$%___
  book A    book B
```